# Getting My ZF Application Seeing My Subdomain Routes

Tags: zend-framework, routes, subdomain

I'm working on a project that I'm using Zend_Hostname_Router_Route for.

My application is fairly simple. I have a a module named dev which I want to route to the dev subdomain. I have read a few articles on here and other sites to try to get a idea of what the problem is.

I am using ZF 1.12 for my application. I'm using the Zend_Hostname_Router_Route in my appllication.ini file as listed below:

```
   [production]


    phpSettings.display_errors = 0
    includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
    bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
    bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
    appnamespace = "Application"
    resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
    resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules" 
    resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
    resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
    resources.view[] =
    resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
    resources.view.doctype = "HTML5"
    resources.view.contentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
    phpSettings.display_errors = 1
    resources.db.adapter = "PDO_SQLITE"
    resources.db.params.dbname = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/guestbook.db"  

         [development:production]

    phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
    phpSettings.display_errors = 1
    resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
    resources.db.adapter = "PDO_SQLITE"
    resources.db.params.dbname = APPLICATION_PATH "/..application/db/guestbook-dev.db"

    resources.router.routes.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
    resources.router.routes.route = "dev.michaeldrowan.com"
    resources.router.routes.chains.dev.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
    resources.router.routes.chains.dev.route = ":controller/:action/"
    resources.router.routes.chains.dev.defaults.module = "dev"
    resources.router.routes.chains.dev.defaults.controller = "index"
    resources.router.routes.chains.dev.defaults.action = "index"
```

The application in the ZF quickstart tutorial. So I shouldn't have problems setting this up. I have tried two index.php. On in public_html and one in subdomain in folder below(that is where my host puts it in). The index in the subdomain points to the dev module..I also tried the  way of doing it that is how the zf quickstart tutorial

```
  <?php
   // Define path to application directory
    defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
        || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../michaeldrowan   /application/'));


   // Define application environment
   defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
      || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')  : 'production'));


   // Ensure library/ is on include_path
    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

    /** Zend_Application */
   require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

    // Create application, bootstrap, and run
    $application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
?>
```

and the index in the dev is:

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
?>
```

I have tried to point to the module in both by changing the 'production' to 'development'. I even tried 'development : production'

I've also tried to point the application to the module config and tried setting the application to the module too.

I'm running out of things to try. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache write this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z\-\.]+)\.yoursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?someparam=%1 [QSA]
```

Then you can access subdomain name in your IndexController:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('someparam') == 'dev') {
  // use routing
}
```